# Emulating types in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, python-descriptors

I am working on a smartcard application which reads bytecode from a card.

I want a `<A>Field()` class which is supposed to represent a field holding data of `<type 'A'>`, to be instantiated with a bytecode value, which I want to manipulate as naturaly as possible.

```
#ex.: to instatiate a new IntField with value 31611

IntField([0, 0, 123, 123])
```

I thought of something like this:

```
class IntField(object):

    value = None
    bytecode = []

    def __init__(self, bytecode):
        self.bytecode = bytecode
        # decodes bytecode to int
        self.decode()

    def __get__(self):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        # encodes new value into bytecode
        self.encode()

    # magic methods to opperate with int

    def some_behavior(self):
        print 'some_behavior'

    def decode(self):
        # applies decoding
        self.value = new_value

    def encode(self):
        # applies encoding
        self.bytecode = new_bytecode
```

So I could use as follwoing:

```
>>> a = IntField([0, 0, 0, 3])
>>> print a
3
>>> a.some_behavior()
some_behavior
>>> print type(a)
<class '__main__.IntField'>
>>> a = 4 + a
>>> print a
7
>>> print type(a)
<class '__main__.IntField'>
>>> a.some_behavior()
>>> a = 23
>>> print a.bytecode
[0, 0, 0, 17]
>>> print type(a)
<class '__main__.IntField'>
```

I know this can be done as I have seen [implementations of the concept](https://github.com/nuigroup/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx). But they go down to C level to make it happen. Is there a simpler, pure python way of doing this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read this guide to pythons magic methods.  In particular, you shoudl look into defining `__add__` to returning a `MyField` object.  https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods

Comment: You can't overload assignment. In Python, assignment is an operation of the namespace holding whatever you're assigning to, not an operation of the object bound to the name.

Comment: [Emulating numeric types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: You can have an object overload *index* assignment or *attribute* assignment, but if you have `a = MyField(3)`, `MyField` has no say over what assignment to `a` does.

Comment: @user2357112. Why would it need to? The OP is trying to preserve the type, not the instance.

Comment: @ekhumoro: It sounds like they want `4 + a` to be an ordinary `7`, but `a = 4 + a` to keep `a` as a `MyField`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I hid those definitions thinking it would be a more direct approach, now that you have said this, and taking a hint from @ekhumoro's comment, would `def __add__(self, value):return MyField(self.value + value)`suffice?

Comment: @user2357112. I know. But it's the operation that affects the type, not the assignment. The title of the question should probably be changed.

Comment: `__get__` and `__set__` are for descriptors. They are not needed in the Field class.

Comment: @ekhumoro, you are right on the money

Comment: @Gribouillis: don't I need at least `__get__` in order to lookup the `value` of my field?

Comment: In principle, no. But it may depend on what you want to do with the Field class.

Comment: @GugaFigueiredo. Is `MyField` supposed to contain arbitrary data, or only integers? If the latter, why isn't it a subclass of `int`?

Comment: @ekhumoro: I thought of that.. but I read somewhere that was not encouraged. There are some caveats to this situation.. I am going to edit my question to elaborate on the problem.

Comment: Or maybe I might ask a new question as even the title would have to change

Comment: I'll have to edit , title and all, as I cannot pos again for a while

Comment: Yeah, you still can't do that. `a` has no control over what happens when you do `a = 23`. The examples you think prove it can be done are for object attributes.

Comment: @user2357112: say that is what I want, to work with attributes, is there a way to do that then? other than the examples I posted, that is

Comment: @GugaFigueiredo: Use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: @GugaFigueiredo. The example with `a = 23` is not in any way "natural". Imagine that `a` was a normal python `list` - would you really expect its type to still be `list` after you assigned `23` to it? Python variables just do not work that way. (All the other requested behaviours have already been covered in other comments).

Comment: @ekhumoro. Maybe my question doesn't yet cover what I really want, sorry. As @user2357112 sugested, I should use `IntField` as a property. Probem now arises from the fact that, as a property, I cannot access its inner methods and attributes outside since I have implemented `__get__`. So lets say I have an object with an `a = IntField()` property, a call like `my_object.a.some_method` won't work because calling `my_object.a` returns a type 'int'. Is there a work around for this? is it possible to work around this by implementing `__new__` instead?

Comment: @GugaFigueiredo. Using a property doesn't make things any better - it's still completely unintuitive. After making an assignment, the type of the left-hand side should match the type of the right-hand side. There may be rare ambiguous cases where this is not possible - but yours isn't one of them. I really don't understand why you are insisting on this weird assignment behaviour. If you want a variable/property to be an `IntField`, just do this: `obj.a = IntField(23)`. Explicit is better than implicit.